# How to enable absolute paths in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I have one document under ~/my_files/test.tex and want to include in test.tex some styling informations, which can be found under ~/latex/styles/info_hypersetup.tex.

When I include the following statement into my test.tex:

```
%% setting the infos for the pdf
\include{home/helex/latex/styles/info_hypersetup.tex}
```

I get the following error when running pdflatex test.test:

```
! I can't write on file `~/latex/styles/info_hypersetup.tex.aux'.
```

I set the rights to 777 but this doesn't changed anything. It works, if I put info_hypersetup.tex in the directory-structure where test.tex is. But I want to use this styleinformation as a global setting for all my documents and don't want to copy it into every project.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is the directory `~/latex/styles/` writable?

Comment: Hi KennyTM,

yes I set it with sudo chmod -R 777 ~/latex and the error is still the same.

Comment: Add it to your local TeXmf tree (~/texmf/tex/latex/local/) and then run texhash (as you, *not* as root). You then should be able to do \include{info_hypersetup.tex}. BTW, I suspect you actually want to \input this file: \include is meant for stuff to be typeset. (There are good security reasons for forbidding the type of path you've tried to use.)

Answer (score 5):

`~` is not a path in Unix, rather it is a path that Unix shells expand to the value of $HOME.

You've got a few possible ways to solve your problem:

1. Define a macro `\homedir` whose value is coded in your Latex file to be the absolute path to your home (i.e., the contents of $HOME).  Nonportable: if you move your file to another machine, it probably won't work.
2. Use relative paths: this is what your solution does.  If you move subhierarchies of files about, and are careful that that are self-contained, this works well.
3. Create your own style file, say `thisfilesystem.sty`, with hardcoded values for various directories.  You can then just change the values of this from machine to machine.  This can also be created automatically from a Makefile.
4. Use `\write18` to run `echo $HOME` and bind this to you `\homedir` macro.  It's portable, but I don't advise it: you should get into the habit of avoiding `\write18`, because it is an awful security hole.

I'd recommend #2.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my *dirty* solution (because many people out there says not to use input but I want to get on :)):

```
\newcommand{\home}{../..}
\input{\home/latex/styles/info_hypersetup}
```

If you find something better, just let me know. The hint with setting output_any = a int the texmf.conf didn't work. I'm using ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

**Problem:**
You forget to close the pdf that you are creating or compiling.

**Solution:**
Just close you adobe reader or whatever application you are reading the pdf file.